# Bounded variation as the difference of two non-increasing functions possible (defined via finite signed measure)?

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convolution, bounded-variation

If we have a **finite** signed measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ and we define the following function
$$
F(x)=\mu([x,\infty))
$$
can we conclude that this function is of bounded variation? I tried to use the Jordan decomposition to get $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ which then is
$$F
(x)=\mu^+([x,\infty))-\mu^-([x,\infty))
$$
but the problem is, that this is the difference of two decreasing (non-increasing) functions. For the bounded variation we would need that it is the difference of two non-decreasing functions, so this somehow does not work. Anything I can do about it?

**For the context:** I wanted to show that the convolution of the finite signed measure with an indicator function is of bounded variation, so
$$
\mu\ast1_{(-\infty,t]}(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}1_{(-\infty,t]}(x-y)\mu(dy)=\mu(x-t,\infty)
$$

Idea:

$F$ is of bounded variation if $-F$ is of bounded variation (is this correct?).
If so, we could re-write the above and get
$$
G(x)=-F(x)=-\Big(\mu^+([x,\infty))-\mu^-([x,\infty))\Big)=-\mu^+([x,\infty))-\Big(-\mu^-([x,\infty))\Big)
$$
now $-G$ would be the difference of two non-decreasing functions and hence of bounded variation. Does this argument work?

Comment: $F(x)=\mu[x,\infty)$. $F(x)+\mu(-\infty,x)=\mu(-\infty,\infty)$. $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,\infty)-\mu(-\infty,x)$. $\mu(-\infty,x)$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts ah...nice catch. That seems to work. Any idea on my approach, should actually work as well since a sign doesn't make any difference in adding up the increments in definition of total variation, am I correct?

Comment: That's how I see it.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts yeah...then we are two already, I was just irritated that I couldn't find any statement a la $F$ is of BV iff $-F$. I like your approach too so if you like just post it as an answer!

Comment: You trivially have $F(x) = -\mu^-([x,\infty)) - (-\mu^+([x,\infty)))$. Hence, it is the difference of two non-decreasing functions.

Comment: @gerw ha, of course! that's even better...